# Intercept the message "no application can perform this action" while sending an email - Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to intercept the message "no application can perform this action" when I start an Intent to send an email. Look at the following code :

```
            Intent i2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i2.setType("message/rfc822");
            i2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , "blabla@gmail.com");
            i2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
            i2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is a test");
            try 
            {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i2, "Mail ..."));
            } 
            catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "no email client installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

When you don't have an email client installed on your device the app says "No application can perform this action" but I would like to display my own message. The code I wrote doesn't work for that.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) instead.